# Is there a way to supress p-values in tbl_regression function in R?

Tags: r, regression

To test whether there is an association between disease groups (categorical_variable) and a disease (outcome; count) I am running 3 negative binomial regression models.

To display the ORs and CIs i am using the `tbl_regression` function from the package `gtsummary`. However, this function displays CIs delineated with comma's, where I want them between brackets, and displays p-values, which I want to supress alltogether.

My code:

```
library(gtsummary)

model <- glm(data=data, formula=outcome ~ categorical_variable)

tbl_regression(model,
    exponentiate = TRUE, 
    include="categorical_variable")
```

Any help on formatting the CI's and supressing the p-value column?

I tried adding `%>% as_gt() %>% cols_hide("p-value")` as well as `%>% as_gt() %>% cols_hide(columns=vars("p-value"))` but to no avail. It says it does not recognize p-value as a column (also does not work without brackets).

Comment: Could you please include what package this function is from? Otherwise, if it is a `data.frame`, just remove the column?

Comment: Edited the post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `res` is the object from the above question that is a `gtsummary` object, one can modify the table body shown in the viewer pane as follows. Here, I am using `dplyr`'s `select` function (`modify_table_body` expects a function) to exclude the p value column.

`gtsummary::modify_table_body(res, dplyr::select, -p.value)`

I want to use only `base`:

```
p_val_col<-which(names(res$table_body)=="p.value")

gtsummary::modify_table_body(res, `[`, -p_val_col)
```

To also modify the display of `ci` (you can probably write a much simpler regex than this), run as follows (simulataneously). One could probably write a function that does this at once instead of calling `modify_table_body` twice:

```
gtsummary::modify_table_body(res, `[`, -23) %>% 
  gtsummary::modify_table_body(., dplyr::mutate, 
                               ci=gsub("(\\d\\.\\d{,4})(, )(\\d\\.\\d{,4})"
                                                         ,"\\[\\1 \\3\\]",ci))
```

Comment: There is also `modify_column_hide()`  which won't change the object.

Comment: Great! Thanks.
It already produced the desired result after `gtsummary::modify_table_body(res, dplyr::select, -p.value)`. Would you also know a way of altering the CIs so they are presented between brackets in stead of with a comma between them?

Many thanks!

Comment: @tcvdb1992 Please check the edit. This RegEx assumes that we shall always have digits of the form `0.00` that is 0+dot+at most four digits.

Comment: Thanks! I also fixed the first p-value problem by adding
`  modify_column_hide(column=p.value)`

Comment: The CIs are now displayed without a '-' between them.. Would your code also allow for that to be the case?

Comment: Sorry, for the slow response. If you still need this, you can change `\\[\\1 \\3\\]` to `"\\[\\1-\\3\\]"` which will make them of the form `[0.0001-0.0001]`(random numbers just). @tcvdb1992

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned by Elin for the single table case:

```
tbl_regression(model,
  exponentiate = TRUE, 
  include="categorical_variable") %>%
  modify_column_hide(columns = p.value)
```

For the case with two (or more) regression models:

```
tbl_merge(
    tbls = list(tbl_regression(model1),
                tbl_regression(model2))
    )  %>% 
    modify_column_hide(columns = c(p.value_1, p.value_2)
```